# How to check the Groovy assert return?

Tags: grails, groovy, assertion

My assert statement

```
assert actualObject==expectedObject : "Verify Status"
```

How can I validate the return statement(TRUE or FALSE) of the above assert statement?

Like

```
if(WebUI.verifyEqual(actualObject, expectedObject)==true){
```

My purpose:
if it's True I will do something, else I throw the assert error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645142/groovy-assert-how-to-display-the-value is related

Answer (score 2):

> How can I validate the return statement(TRUE or FALSE) of the above
> assert statement?
>
> My purpose: if it's True I will do something, else I throw the assert
> error

That is what will happen if you do this:

```
assert actualObject==expectedObject : "Verify Status"
```

**EDIT:**

@daggett left a comment below indicating "i believe he don't want to throw error".  If that is the case the question isn't clear but you can do that simply with an `if`:

```
if(actualObject==expectedObject) {
    // do something
} else {
    // don't throw an error
}
```

Or:

```
if(WebUI.verifyEqual(actualObject, expectedObject)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // don't throw an error
}
```

Comment: i believe he don't want to throw error

Comment: "i believe he don't want to throw error" - The question says the purpose includes " else I throw the assert error".